# Product of Lebesgue with counting measure

Tags: measure-theory

I was given the following question. I know how to answer the first part, but I am confused on the last part... "Show that, for each.."

Any help on the last part will be greatly appreciated.

[image: 1]

Comment: Where does the problem come from? Google suggests https://people.clas.ufl.edu/mjury/files/6616notes18nov2015.pdf or https://people.clas.ufl.edu/pascoej/files/6616notes01dec2017.pdf

Comment: Yes, I was able to do the first part without issue, I am just stuck on the last part.